# Android Vanilla Froyo Theme In Gingerbread App

Tags: android, android-theme

I really liked the look of dialogs (rounded/grey translucent) and buttons (rounded/gradient) in Froyo as my app was built around that theme. However when my app is run in Gingerbread, the default dark theme really ruins the look.

I'm wondering is there an easy way to bring the Froyo look to Gingerbread just for my app? I would like to keep the UI of my app consistent across all versions of Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to save all the resources locally in your app and then use the styles for the gingerbread version. 
Check where you downloaded the sdk after the correct platform and then go into data/res/ and you will see all the resources folders. Get all the resources you need and put them in your project.

Comment: I've started copying over the files but the dependencies keep me copying more and more files and it's making my app unnecessarily bigger. Where (in which files) can I copy over the least amount possible? I'm not too familiar with themes and styling.

Comment: Noone can really tell you that since we do not know which themes/styles you want to keep or which ones you use. Check values/styles.xml and copy the ones you use, or want to use like Buttons and alertDialogs and such. You will probably also need to copy the corresponding drawables for the different styles.

Comment: Sounds good. It'll be a lot of work to comb through it but figured I take the time now to do it as I can reuse it in other projects later.